# Fragment IllegalStateException when reusing inflated fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I cache the fragments (have very few of them) as they are view intensive and inflate takes time which i am trying to avoid.

So in each fragment class we have static View currentView = null; which is populated once that fragment calls on ViewCreate.

```
    if (currentView == null)
        currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
```

Now i am 99% sure this worked before that i could do the following:

```
Fragment_proxydisplay_menu menu = new Fragment_proxydisplay_menu(); //instantiated and entered some items for the menu
menu.AddItems("1","2");
```

And eventually called fragment manager to display this created fragment:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, menu, menu.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Now the IllegalStateException comes into play if one of my items triggers a submenu i do the above again with different items and get

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5124)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4953)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4893)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.addViewToContainer(FragmentStateManager.java:840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:529)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1808)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:614)
```

If i show a another lets say "please wait" simple fragment between to menu fragments it works. And I am sure this worked in sdk 25 or less because now is the first time I am getting this.

I tried removing the parent from currentView as per some research:

```
    if(currentView == null)
        currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_proxydisplay_menu, container, false);
    else
        ((ViewGroup) currentView.getParent()).removeView(currentView);
```

Now i do not track which fragment is on screen as they are prettymuch selfcontained so why would this error start to happen in the newer sdk? How can i reuse the inflated fragment and repaint it with different data without knowing that i must not use the same screen in a row.

**Edit 1 - DOES NOT WORK as other fragments then get only white screen - WHY ? :S**

Some new information, playing with this over weekend and focusing more on the fragment manager. So my fragmentmanager for adding the fragment looked like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, menu, menu.getClass().getSimpleName());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Adding a remove before replace/commit stopped the illegalstateexception:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    String tag = menu.getClass().getSimpleName();

    //adding these three lines removes the error
    Fragment currentFragment =  fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if(currentFragment != null && currentFragment.getClass().equals(tag))
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, menu, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Question why would this help ? Or is it working and masking the root problem ? Shouldn't replace do the same thing as remove and add in the fragment manager transaction?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use static views, fragment and activities... It's a bad idea

Comment: @GobuCSG I generally agree, but what is the alternative, having a for example very special keyboard with a lot of buttons with efects etc... inflate takes time. how to avoid the inflate ? This was the only thing i was trying to achieve. Inflate only once and reuse

Comment: Can you attach your screenshot... Don't share a link

Comment: @GobuCSG i think i found a problem the problem was indeed a static View which i had stored in the fragment class, removing the static and reusing the instance with the View stored as part of that instance shows no remove child from parent issue. Will test more and post an answer for anyone coming to the same problem